# PHP CodeIgniter : How to retrieve names of all controllers programatically?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is doable by recursively reading filenames in PHP.
But is there any already existing method in Router Class or some other class which can give me names of all controllers ?

Background:
I want to assign URLs to users like :
`http://www.example.com/my_user_name`

But would not want to have any `my_user_name` equal to any of CI controllers.

Comment: is there any reason why you don't want to pass that as part of a url segment?

Comment: @Daz Yes, `http://www.site.com/THEUSERNAME` seems to be the standard practice followed on most web portals to assign vanity urls. `http://www.site.com/ONE_CONTROLLER/THEUSERNAME` does not seem appropriate considering the practice.

Comment: @Daz  SO being Exception here :D \

Comment: @DhruvPathak you can always remove the controller name via htaccess, no need to overcomplicate things. Also, is this related to your previous question? Just to think at solutions keeping in mind that

Comment: @DamienPirsy Yes, somewhat related. Searching for generic solution to serve both purposes.

Comment: @DamienPirsy ,Did you see my last edit in previous question ? Your answer may need some editing based on that.However,I still could not find any solution for that apart from editing Router.php library.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but hadn't time to think well at it. Questions are tricky, and I can't think of an easy way to combine the two solutions, apart from a catch-all controller and maybe some url rewriting with htaccess. And I have a feeling you're making things too complicated and a rethinking of the design architecture might help that, but I just know this two things from your app so I really can't tell

Comment: @DamienPirsy sadly this tricky bit is mandatory. The URL requirement is this way only.

Comment: I know that, but why aren't you taking into consideration htaccess rewrite rules? or the catch-all controller I suggested in my answer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5516/discussion-between-dhruvpathak-and-damien-pirsy)

Comment: Sorry I can't chat right now, I'm going out in some minutes (7.40 am here, going to work), but if I find time I could later

Comment: How do you plan to structure your uri's? is it site.com/THEUSERNAME/ONE_CONTROLLER

Comment: @Daz  www.site.com/THEUSERNAME for user profiles www.site.com/CONTROLERNAME/METHODNAME... for all other pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method within CodeIgniter that can provide you with that information.

The CodeIgniter Router tries to load the controller asked for with the passed URL segments. It doesn't load all controllers, since this would have no purpose.

A suggestion would be [extending the router](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) and adding your desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$files = get_dir_file_info(APPPATH.'controllers', FALSE);

    // Loop through file names removing .php extension
    foreach (array_keys($files) as $file)
    {
        $controllers[] = str_replace(EXT, '', $file);
    }
    print_r($controllers);
```

Comment: OP simply said `This is doable by recursively reading filenames in PHP. But is there any already existing method..?`  This is what he's trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `$route['404_override'] = 'users';` that way anything not found will hit your users controller. If no user is found then just show_404().

Comment: but lets say www.mysite.com/USER_NAME has 404, and 404 override goes to `users` controller, how can I retreive USER_NAME in `user` controller using Router class ?

Comment: You can just use the uri segment: $this->uri->segment(1) then if not found manually throw your 404.

Answer (score 0):

It`s possible using pragmatically - please follow these steps

1) Create this library with **ControllerList.php** and save into **application/libraries** directory.

**Library -**

```
    <?php
    if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
        exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class ControllerList {

        /**
         * Codeigniter reference 
         */
        private $CI;

        /**
         * Array that will hold the controller names and methods
         */
        private $aControllers;

        // Construct
        function __construct() {
            // Get Codeigniter instance 
            $this->CI = get_instance();

            // Get all controllers 
            $this->setControllers();
        }

        /**
         * Return all controllers and their methods
         * @return array
         */
        public function getControllers() {
            return $this->aControllers;
        }

    /**
     * Set the array holding the controller name and methods
     */
    public function setControllerMethods($p_sControllerName, $p_aControllerMethods) {
        $this->aControllers[$p_sControllerName] = $p_aControllerMethods;
    }

    /**
     * Search and set controller and methods.
     */
    private function setControllers() {
        // Loop through the controller directory
        foreach(glob(APPPATH . 'controllers/*') as $controller) {

            // if the value in the loop is a directory loop through that directory
            if(is_dir($controller)) {
                // Get name of directory
                $dirname = basename($controller, EXT);

                // Loop through the subdirectory
                foreach(glob(APPPATH . 'controllers/'.$dirname.'/*') as $subdircontroller) {
                    // Get the name of the subdir
                    $subdircontrollername = basename($subdircontroller, EXT);

                    // Load the controller file in memory if it's not load already
                    if(!class_exists($subdircontrollername)) {
                        $this->CI->load->file($subdircontroller);
                    }
                    // Add the controllername to the array with its methods
                    $aMethods = get_class_methods($subdircontrollername);
                    $aUserMethods = array();
                    foreach($aMethods as $method) {
                        if($method != '__construct' && $method != 'get_instance' && $method != $subdircontrollername) {
                            $aUserMethods[] = $method;
                        }
                    }
                    $this->setControllerMethods($subdircontrollername, $aUserMethods);                                      
                }
            }
            else if(pathinfo($controller, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "php"){
                // value is no directory get controller name                
                $controllername = basename($controller, EXT);

                // Load the class in memory (if it's not loaded already)
                if(!class_exists($controllername)) {
                    $this->CI->load->file($controller);
                }

                // Add controller and methods to the array
                $aMethods = get_class_methods($controllername);
                $aUserMethods = array();
                if(is_array($aMethods)){
                    foreach($aMethods as $method) {
                        if($method != '__construct' && $method != 'get_instance' && $method != $controllername) {
                            $aUserMethods[] = $method;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $this->setControllerMethods($controllername, $aUserMethods);                                
            }
        }   
    }
}

?>
```

2) Now load this library and using that you can fetch all controllers and methods accordingly.

```
$this->load->library('controllerlist');

print_r($this->controllerlist->getControllers());
```

**Output will be like that -**

```
Array
(
    [academic] => Array
        (
            [0] => index
            [1] => addno
            [2] => addgrade
            [3] => viewRecordByStudent
            [4] => editStudentRecord
            [5] => viewRecordByClass
            [6] => viewRecordByTest
            [7] => viewGradeByClass
            [8] => editGrade
            [9] => issueMarksheet
            [10] => viewIssueMarksheet
            [11] => checkRecordStatus
            [12] => checkRecordData
            [13] => checkStudentRecordData
            [14] => insertGrades
            [15] => updateGrades
            [16] => updateRecords
            [17] => insertStudentNo
            [18] => getRecordDataByStudent
            [19] => getRecordDataByClass
            [20] => getGradesDataByClass
            [21] => deleteGrades
            [22] => insertIssueMarksheet
            [23] => getIssuedMarksheets
            [24] => printMarksheet
        )

    [attendance] => Array
        (
            [0] => index
            [1] => holidays
            [2] => deleteHoliday
            [3] => addHoliday
            [4] => applications
            [5] => deleteApplication
            [6] => addApplication
            [7] => insertApplication
            [8] => applcationByClass
            [9] => applcationByPeriod
            [10] => applcationByStudent
            [11] => getApplicationsByClass
            [12] => getApplicationsByPeriod
            [13] => getApplicationsByStudent
            [14] => attendanceforstudent
            [15] => attendanceforfaculty
            [16] => getStudentsForAttendance
            [17] => feedStudentAttendance
            [18] => sendAbsentStudents
            [19] => particularStudent
            [20] => monthlyWiseStudents
            [21] => dailyAttedance
            [22] => feedFacultyAttendance
            [23] => particularFaculty
            [24] => monthlyWiseFaculty
            [25] => editStudentAttendance
            [26] => updateStudentAttendance
        )

)
```

please apply this and let me know if you have any issues.